# retrieving a json file using retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

My MainActivity has Base url, I am trying to retrieve a json file from the server, using retrofit.

Here's a part of the code in MainActivity

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_get_data) {
            if (isOnline()) {
                requestData();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Network isn't available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void requestData() {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ENDPOINT)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        FlowersAPI service = retrofit.create(FlowersAPI.class);
        Call<List<Flower>> call = service.getFeed();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Flower>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Flower>> call, Response<List<Flower>> response) {
                         flowerList = response.body();
                updateDisplay();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Flower>> call, Throwable t) {

            }

        });

    }

    protected void updateDisplay() {
        //Use FlowerAdapter to display data
        FlowerAdapterPicaso adapter = new FlowerAdapterPicaso(this,
                R.layout.item_flower, flowerList);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

And here is my interface

```
public interface FlowersAPI {

    @GET("/feeds/flowers.json")
    public Call<List<Flower>> getFeed();

}
```

I am unable to get the result i.e no data in the listview, every other example shows retrofit from previous versions, and my other question is? Is it compulsory to add GsonConverterFactory.

Comment: I am using the latest version of retrofit, and is it necessary to use OkHttpClient as seen in some other examples?

Comment: `Unable to create converter ` ... Why did you comment the GsonConverterFactory?

Comment: even using GsonConverterFactory giving me error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/gson/Gson;
                                                                                at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonConverterFactory.java:42)
                                                                                at com.hanselandpetal.catalog.MainActivity.requestData(MainActivity.java:69)

Comment: That means you didn't completely read the documentation to include `com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson` as a dependency

Comment: No I added the dependency jar file, before adding the jar file the GsonCovertorFactory class is not recognized

Comment: After I added the dependency only it compiled.

Comment: Wait, are you using Gradle, or JAR files?

Comment: First I tried to compile using gradle, android studio gave me error, then I searched in maven repo and found converter-gson.jar and added the jar

Comment: Did you also add the [Gson](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson) JAR as a dependency? You need that in order to use the converter. Or you could show your Gradle file and the error you were having, and I could help with that

Comment: no i didnt add GSON, but after adding GSON to gradle i am getting no data back.I also updated my question. Please someone help.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you're missing the HTTP client for requests, before creating the API service.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(ENDPOINT)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder().build())
        .build();
```